Accessing old Staging Ground beta discussions
I was not part of the staging ground beta. When I search Meta to see if a discussion has already been started on a feature request for Staging Grounds has been proposed/is in the works, I often see comments with links to discussions in the beta. E.g.: Followed Posts in Staging Ground don't show up in profile has the following comment:

This was already reported in the beta and is currently marked [status-review].

The beta is private. Is there a way retroactively join it for access to the archives, or can parts of those archives that are still relevant be made public somehow?

Currently, the answer is no, but...it's a reasonable question to ask.  I'm not sure if there's a good way to make an archive of a Team public, though, nor is there really a particularly scalable way to handle access requests.

@RyanM If somebody was in the beta, are they free to paste any relevant sections of discussions to meta, now that it's over? Or are there NDAs or sensitive information that they would need to be careful of?

Good question!  I'm not sure (I don't think I signed an NDA regarding that...but I could have forgotten/implicitly agreed that it was covered as information being given to me as a mod, etc.), but I can ask around.  If there are particular things that someone thinks would be useful, it's also probably not too hard to just ask the author.  Most of the people in the beta are fairly active and not too hard to get in contact with.

If I remember correctly we didn't sign an NDA.

I'm sure a few of us beta testers, and (ex-)Staff, have quoted content from the Team to places like here on Meta, both during and after the Beta(s), and had no pushback from Staff. That doesn't help other users see the content, however, it does at least mean that we can likely provide quotes and screenshots if needed.

i can't speak for others but when I post comments like that, I'm adding that so that people with access (other beta testers and possibly staff members) can easily find the other post if necessary and also as information for the (new) asker ("and is currently marked [status-review]").
